# Qemu: No file system could mount root (unable to mount roofs)

Tags: kernel, mount, linux-kernel, qemu, root-filesystem

In Linux, I've created the root file system (rootfs) by following commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=ramdisk.img bs=1M count=4
mkfs.ext2 ramdisk.img
sudo mount -o loop ramdisk.img rootfs
sudo cp init rootfs 
sudo mkdir rootfs/dev
sudo mknod rootfs/dev/console c 5 1
sudo mknod rootfs/dev/ram b 1 0
sudo umount rootfs
```

but when I run qemu by following command, it say: No file system could mount root

```
qemu -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage  -initrd ../qemu-i386/ramdisk.img  -append "root=/dev/ram init=/init"
```

[image]

What the problem with my instructions?

Comment: The only thing immediately jumping out of me is that it should be `root=/dev/ram0` not `root=/dev/ram`. Not sure if this is a strict requirement though. But the kernel docs explicitly say it should be `/dev/ram0`.

Comment: @Patrick changing /dev/ram to /dev/ram0 doen't works. Can you introduce me some resource to learn creating rootfs?

Comment: I was just going off the `initrd.txt` file in the Documentation directory of the kernel source. Another thought, are you sure you have initrd support enabled in the kernel? I personally don't use initrd any more. Initramfs is the more modern way of doing init root filesystems.